# CUDD: how to count the number of nodes and edges of a decision diagram?

Tags: cudd

I have a pointer to the root node of a CUDD decision diagramm, say

```
DdNode * root
```

How can I retrieve the number of nodes and edges composing this decision tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Cudd_DagSize()`](http://www.async.ece.utah.edu/~myers/nobackup/ee5740_98/cudd/cuddAllDet.html#Cudd_DagSize) to get the number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

on cuddUtil.c read the function :

```
int Cudd_PrintDebug(DdManager * dd,DdNode * f,int  n,int  pr);
```

you can get the number of nodes :

```
Cudd_DagSize(root);
```

number of leaves :

```
Cudd_CountLeaves(root);
```

number of minterms :

```
Cudd_CountMinterm(dd, root, n);
```

and more ...